# Alteração de entidade refletir nas entidades relacionadas

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

Tenho duas entidades, por exemplo:

*Obs: Código fictício para facilitar o entendimento do problema.*

```
@Entity
public class Celular{
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy= GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int id;
    private String modelo;
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "celular")
    private List<chamada> chamadas;
}

@Entity
public class Chamada{
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy= GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int id;
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "idcelular")
    private Celular celular;
}
```

Ocorre que ao alterar o atributo do objeto Celular, este não é refletido no objeto Chamada. Exemplo:

```
...
Chamada ch=celular.getChamada().get(0);
System.out.println(ch.getCelular().getModelo()); //imprime "NOKIA"

celular.setModelo("Motorola");

//persistir
getEntityManager().getTransaction().begin();
celular = getEntityManager().merge(entity);
getEntityManager().getTransaction().commit();
getEntityManager().close();

Chamada ch=celular.getChamada().get(0);
System.out.println(celular.getModelo()); //imprime "Motorola"
System.out.println(ch.getCelular().getModelo()); //imprime "Nokia"
```

Qual seria o procedimento correto para que o objeto `chamada` perceba a alteração em `celular`?

Comment: Seu problema deve estar na hora de salvar o relacionamento.

Você deve sempre fazer a.setB(b) e b.set(A). Tenha certeza de efetuar corretamente os relacionamentos antes de persistir no DB.

Answer (score 1):

Tente fazer [entityManager.refresh](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/EntityManager.html#refresh(java.lang.Object))(celular);

> Refresh the state of the instance from the database, overwriting changes made to the entity, if any.

Comment: Seria o mesmo que fazer um celular=getEntityManager().find(Celular.class, celular.getId()); ?

Comment: O refresh recebe uma entidade e atualiza os atributos dela com os dados do banco de dados (suponha que uma outra transação concorrente tenha dado commit, e você quer ter certeza que está com os dados atualizados). O find, a partir de uma primary key, recupera uma entidade do contexto persistence, o que pode acontecer aqui, dependendo da sua configuração, o entitymanager não necessáriamente irá descer no banco de dados direto (ele pode pegar alguma referência já obtida anteriormente [caso alguma outra transação tenha feito alterações nos dados, a que está em memória não irá ver as alterações]).

Comment: Links de referência para os métodos citados:

find: http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/EntityManager.html#find(java.lang.Class, java.lang.Object) 
refresh: http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/EntityManager.html#refresh(java.lang.Object)